# Find out the local maxima/minima of $x^3$ in $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Find out the local maxima/minima of $x^3$ in $[0,1]$?

$$f'(x)=3x^2$$

At $x=0$ we have $f'(x)=0$. But as we know that $x=0$ is the point of inflection.

On the other hand $x<0$ is not in the domain, so in the given interval $[0,1]$, 
$x=0$ satisfies the condition of minima.

So what is the correct way to go in such cases?

Comment: As a note, $x=0$ is not only an inflection point, is also part of the boundary of your domain. Being a boundary point means you have to check if in that point there is a minima or maxima. In this case both minima and maxima are the extremes of your interval, the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

In this fairly simple case, you don't need to actually use derivatives. Instead, note $f(x) = x^3$ is a strictly increasing function for $x \ge 0$ (which you can also see since $f'(x) = 3x^2 \gt 0$ for $x \gt 0$, or that if $y \gt x \ge 0$, then $f(y) - f(x) = y^3 - x^3 = (y - x)(y^2 + yx + x^2) \gt 0$). Thus, for $x \in [0,1]$, the local minimum would be $f(0) = 0$ and the local maximum would be $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: I am asking for local minima/maxima and the point is that at $x=0$, we have the point of inflection, so should we consider $x=0$ as minima?

Comment: @prat It's a point of inflection in the global sense, i.e., where you're considering values of $x$ both less than and greater than $0$. However, for the local closed region of $[0,1]$, since it's on the boundary, it's a minimum here since $f(x)$ is increasing for values $\gt 0$.